# Plot function and Scatter on the same graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot the function y = x**2 and a scatter on the same graph. I have found lots of people talking about having two functions or two scatters on the same graph but I was wondering if anyone knows how to plot a function and a scatter on the same graph. I am using Python with the matplotlib library.

Comment: Often if you browse through [The Matplotlib Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) you can find an example that has [features you want](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_masked.html) and you can look at how they were made/implemented then adapt it to your own circumstances. If adapting those examples for your use seems hard you should probably spend some (well worth) time with [the Tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the respective functions of the matplotlib module:

```py
from matplolib import pyplot as plt
t=np.linspace(x_low,x_high,numpoints)
plt.plot(t,t**2)
plt.scatter(x_data,y_data)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine multiple objects in one figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 1, num=10)
y = x**2
obj1 = plt.plot(x, y)
obj2 = plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Sample run:

```
>>> obj1 #list of all lines
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x228c2de91f0>]
>>> obj2 #collections
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x228c5459a00>
```

Comment: Just a side note, this output looks a slighty different because I work on Jupyter Notebook where `perfplot` was imported in another cell :)

Comment: Perfect. I'm sad that I'm the first one to upvote this. And unlike the accepted answer, this contains the right imports.